# Getting error while loading CSV file into SQL Server in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am unable to load `.csv` file data into SQL Server and throwing error like column delimiter for column was not found.

This is my `.csv` file data

```
Id,fullname,role,date
1,"James,good", manager,2024-01-01
2,"rupesh,naid",assistant,2023-02-01
```

I have specified text qualifier as `"`, and column delimiter as comma (`,`) and row delimiter as `{CR}{LF}`.

I am getting same data in correct format but double quotes not removed from fullname column in flat file connection preview data.

How do I get best results in SQL without throwing error? Please help me

I have tried to load data in flat file connection but throwing error and also getting incorrect format

Comment: If you have double quotes around the value, I assume you have 2 columns with values like `"James,` and `good"`. Sounds like you *didn't* set the text qualifier.

Comment: "james,good" value comes under the single column and also set text qualifier as ".

Comment: That wouldn't happen with the text qualifier. The qualifiers are removed for the value.

Comment: Can you tell me How do I set configurations in flat file connection to achieve desired results.so that I can follow

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load your file with this settings in "Export-Import wizard"
[First step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKaAx.png)

[image: Second step. Please press "Reset columns" button]

Comment: Are you suggesting this as an alternative to SSIS or that SSIS is buggy and should be abandoned?

Comment: I have enabled unicode and followed same process but still fullname column showing double quotes in preview and also after execution ,throwing error like column delimiter for column fullname not found.

Comment: I did it in the the following way: 1. fill the "General"-tab as on the first picture. 2. Selected the "Columns"-tab and press "Rest columns". As you can see on the second picture the are no double quotes and columns names are detected correctly.

Comment: Can you load the data to SQL table,is it throwing any error or sucess?

Comment: All two rows were loaded

Comment: I am working on ssdt 2017 and getting same error.did I miss any thing in the configurations?.I am skipping head rows and applied same ,changed column delimiter for fullname column in advance.this is only working for me.